# How can I get information from an <a href> tag within <div> tags with BeautifulSoup and Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

all. I have a quick question about BeautifulSoup with Python. I have several bits of HTML that look like this (the only differences are the links and product names) and I'm trying to get the link from the "href" attribute.

```
<div id="productListing1" xmlns:dew="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document">
<span id="rank" style="display:none;">94.36</span>
<div class="productPhoto">
    <img src="/assets/images/ocpimages/87684/00131cl.gif" height="82" width="82" />
</div>
<div class="productName">
    <a class="on" href="/Products/ProductInfoDisplay.aspx?SiteId=1&amp;Product=8768400131">CAPRI SUN - JUICE DRINK - COOLERS VARIETY PACK 6 OZ</a>
</div>
<div class="size">40 CT</div>
```

I currently have this Python code:

```
productLinks = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class' : 'on'})
for link in productLinks:
    print link['href']
```

This works (for every link on the page I get something like `/Products/ProductInfoDisplay.aspx?SiteId=1&amp;Product=8768400131`); however, I've been trying to figure out if there's a way to get the link in the "href" attribute without searching explicitly for 'class="on"'. I guess my first question should be whether or not this is the best way to find this information (class="on" seems too generic and likely to break in the future although my CSS and HTML skills aren't that good). I've tried numerous combinations of find, findAll, findAllnext, etc. methods but I can't quite make it work. This is mostly what I had (I rearranged and changed it numerous times):

```
productLinks = soup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'productName'}).find('a', href=True)
```

If this isn't a good way to do this, how can I get to the `<a>` tag from the `<div class="productName">` tag? Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Well, once you have the `<div>`, element, you can get the `<a>` subelement by calling `find()`:

```
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'productName'})
for div in productDivs:
    print div.find('a')['href']
```

However, since the `<a>` is immediately above `<div>`, you can get the `a` attribute from the div:

```
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'productName'})
for div in productDivs:
    print div.a['href']
```

Now, if you want to put all the `<a>` elements in a list, your code above will not work because `find()` just returns one element matched by its criteria. You would get the list of divs and get the subelements from them, for example, using list comprehensions:

```
productLinks = [div.a for div in 
        soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'productName'})]
for link in productLinks:
    print link['href']
```

Answer (score 9):

I am giving this solution in BeautifulSoup4

```
for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='productName'):
    for a in data.find_all('a'):
        print(a.get('href')) #for getting link
        print(a.text) #for getting text between the link
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid those for loops by specifying the index.

```
data = soup.find_all('div', class_='productName')
a_class = data[0].find_all('a')
url_ = a_class[0].get('href')
print(url_)
```